# how can I store a firebase query object in a variable in angular?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a query to a firebase database using ionic. I want to store the the object snapshot.val() in a variable with the objective of displaying its content in my HTML code but I´m struggling with the scope of my upcomingOrders variable.

How can I update my variable inside the callback?

```
  onFetchMyUpcomingOrders(){
    var upcomingOrders = {}
    const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("orders/confirmed");
    ref.orderByChild("client/clientId").equalTo(userId).once("value", (snapshot) => {
        upcomingOrders= snapshot.val()
        console.log(upcomingOrders)
      });
    console.log(upcomingOrders) // Empty object, should contain snapshot.val()
  }
```

It seems like it's updating by value. How can I update it by reference?

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. While the data is being loaded, the function continues to run. When your `console.log()` just before the end of the function executes, the data hasn't been loaded yet. Then when the data becomes available, your callback function is invoked.

So: your `upcomingOrders` variable *is* being set correctly, just not at the moment where you currently want it.

To make this code work, you must move all code that needs the data **into** the callback function. So if you want to update the HTML, you do that from *inside* the callback:

```
onFetchMyUpcomingOrders(){
  var upcomingOrders = {}
  const userId = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("orders/confirmed");
  ref.orderByChild("client/clientId").equalTo(userId).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    upcomingOrders= snapshot.val()
    // TODO: update HTML and do whatever else needs the data
  });
}
```

This is an extremely common pattern when using modern web APIs. Data is loaded asynchronously all the time, and callback such as this (or a more modern equivalent such as [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)) are the only way to deal with it.